# ODBC to .xlsb file is converting numeric data to string

Tags: vba, excel, csv, odbc

I have an .xlsb file that I connect to via ODBC, this information is stored straight into a pivot cache which I then use to play around with. As least four of my columns consistently keep getting stored as text (confirmed by double clicking a section of the pivot table and seeing the green tags telling me it is stored as text) which makes it impossible to do things like summarise as average and so on. I need to find a way to have them go back to numeric values.

I found some other information online that seemed to think that Excel chooses the data type based on the cell formatting, so I updated my code so the entire desired columns are formatted as number ("0.00"), but this has sadly not helped.

The code first grabs information from a directory full of .csv files (code that forces number formatting is here too):

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    Set tgtSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    tgtSheet.Name = objFile.Name

    On Error Resume Next
    With tgtSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & objFile, Destination:=tgtSheet.Range("A1"))
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .Refresh
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' ------ Force data formatting onto columns
    lastRow = FindLastCell(tgtSheet).Row
    For i = 1 To UBound(titleArray)
        currCol = ColumnByTitle(tgtSheet, titleArray(i))
        With tgtSheet
            Set columnRange = .Range(.Cells(1, currCol), Cells(lastRow,     currCol)).EntireColumn
            columnRange.NumberFormat = formatArray(i)
        End With
    Next i
Next objFile
```

Where columnArray and titleArray are length 4 string arrays holding the appropriate column titles and formatting respectively. This then outputs to an .xlsb:

```
    With ThisWorkbook
        strPath = .Path
        strFile = .FullName
        strFileTemp = strPath & "\DBtemp" & ".xlsb"
        .Worksheets(arrSheets).Copy
    End With
```

..and finally the ODB Connection is setup by building the SQL command out of the sheets still open in the current workbook:

```
For i = LBound(arrSheets) To UBound(arrSheets)
    If arrSheets(i) <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
        If strSQL = "" Then
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & arrSheets(i) & "$]"
        Else
            strSQL = strSQL & " UNION ALL SELECT * FROM [" & arrSheets(i) & "$]"
        End If
    End If
Next i

' ------ set up connection string
strCon = _
    "ODBC;" & _
    "DSN=Excel Files;" & _
    "DBQ=" & strFileTemp & ";" & _
    "DefaultDir=" & strPath & ";" & _
    "DriverId=790;" & _
    "MaxBufferSize=2048;" & _
    "PageTimeout=5"

Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal)

' ------ test pivot table to play around with
With pc
    .Connection = strCon
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = strSQL
    Set pt = .CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1"))
    pt.Name = "TestPivot"
End With
```

There's a few things I've left out for clarity's sake, but if they're needed for context please let me know!

Also, the reason I've done it this way (importing csv to sheets, re-outputting them to .xlsb, connecting to that) is because when I tried importing via ADODB recordset I couldn't use slicers at all, which is kinda a necessity in this case.

I'm also aware tools like powerpivot can make very easy work of this, but sadly I can't use them - no admin access on my computer and the process to get things installed is too time consuming/impossible.

Any major help or perhaps pointing out any glaring oversights on my behalf would be very strongly appreciated, I've spent all day trying to fix this!

**Edit1:** changing the filetype from xlsb to xlsx does nothing. Additionally, in either case the formatting for the columns is still set correctly to number ("0.00"). I believe the problem might be in the ODBC part? There doesn't seem to be much helpful documentation for it out there.

**Edit2:** Excel 2010.

**Edit3:** example input from .csv files:

```
Image date, Image time, Anatomy, View, kVp, mAs, EI, DAP, Reject reason, Status

42005, 3.33E-02, Chest, P.A., 124, 1.7, 135, 9.83,, confirmed       
42005, 3.40E-02, Chest, Lat., 124, 3.9, 137, 23.84,, confirmed      
42005, 3.82E-02, Chest, Lat., 124, 1.6, 95, 9.09,, confirmed
```

Comment: try single-stepping the code by using the F8 key. and watch the worksheet, just to try to find out which command messes up the formatting ... this command line is suspicious `columnRange.NumberFormat = formatArray(i)`  ... maybe comment out the line and run the program again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I solved this finally. I completely did away with the step of importing csv files and exporting them as .xlsb as they did not fix the formatting errors in the slightest.  I revisited the code in another workbook that actually creates the .csv files and forced my desired formatting there:

```
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Create string arrays to handle looking for correct columns and setting the proper
' formatting in them so it doesn't convert to varchar when imported again later
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ReDim titleArray(1 To 4)
    titleArray(1) = "kVp"
    titleArray(2) = "mAs"
    titleArray(3) = "EI"
    titleArray(4) = "DAP"

ReDim formatArray(1 To 4)
    formatArray(1) = "0.00"
    formatArray(2) = "0.00"
    formatArray(3) = "0.00"
    formatArray(4) = "0.00"

' ------ Force data formatting onto columns
lastRow = FindLastCell(tgtCSV.Sheets(1)).row
For i = 1 To UBound(titleArray)
    currCol = ColumnByTitle(tgtCSV.Sheets(1), titleArray(i))
    With tgtCSV.Sheets(1)
        Set lastCell = .Range(.Cells(1, currCol), Cells(lastRow, currCol)).EntireColumn
        lastCell.NumberFormat = formatArray(i)
    End With
Next i
```

Then, in my analysis workbook, I simplified the import process to use only the microsoft text driver, and explicitly calling for a newer created version of the pivot table (with other ODBC stuff I'd done it was defaulting to an earlier version that prohibited the use of slicers)

```
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Build the connection string and add the connection
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Workbooks("EXRAnalysis.xlsm").Connections.Add "Test", "", Array( _
        Array("ODBC;DBQ=" & objFolder & ";" & _
            "DefaultDir=" & objFolder & ";"), _
        Array("Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
            "DriverId=27;" & _
            "HDR=Yes;" & _
            "MaxBufferSize=2048"), _
        Array(";MaxScanRows=0;PageTimeout=5;SafeTransactions=0;Threads=3;UserCommitSync=Yes;")), _
        strSQL, 2

' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Create ODBC connection
' TODOTODOTODO: fix so it wipes out old connection or properly overwrites it. Use code
' to update pivot cache pointers to new connection.
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Test"), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14 _
        ).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R1C1", TableName:= _
        "PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Code is a little messy because it used a recorded macro (yuck), but it's serviceable (and not super slow, yay).